# Differentiability of a function under linear restrictions

Tags: calculus, derivatives

This question may be trivial, though I'd just like to make sure I'm not missing anything stupid. Let $f: \mathbb{R}^d\mapsto\mathbb{R}$ be a differentiable function. Consider the subspace
$$
A=\{\mathbf{y} \in \mathbb{R}^d: \, y_1>y_2> \ldots>y_d\} \subset \mathbb{R}^d
$$
and define the function $f_A(\mathbf{y})=f(\mathbf{y}) \boldsymbol{1}(\mathbf{y} \in A)$, where $\boldsymbol{1}(\cdot)$ is the usual indicator function, i.e. $\boldsymbol{1}(\mathbf{y} \in A)=1$ if $\mathbf{y} \in A$ or equals zero viceversa. Is the function $f_A$ differentiable on $A$?

The answer should be trivially "yes", since, denoting by $\nabla f$ the gradient of $f$, for any $\mathbf{y} \in A$ as $\Vert \mathbf{h} \Vert  \approx0 $ we have $\mathbf{y}+\mathbf{h} \in A$ and
$$
\frac{f_A(\mathbf{y}+\mathbf{h})-f_A(\mathbf{y})- \mathbf{h} \cdot \nabla f (\mathbf{y})}{\Vert \mathbf{h} \Vert} \approx \frac{f(\mathbf{y}+\mathbf{h})-f(\mathbf{y})- \mathbf{h} \cdot \nabla f (\mathbf{y})}{\Vert \mathbf{h} \Vert} \approx 0.
$$
Is this correct, or am I missing something? In general, I would say that a function restricted to a subset of its support obtained by imposing some linear restricitons should preserve all the differentiability properties of the original function.

Comment: $A$ is an open set and $f_A$ is same as $f$ on $A$. So it is obviuosuly differentiable on $A$.

Answer (score 1):

If a function $f$ is differentiable on a given set $A \subseteq \mathbb{R}^n$, then it will be differentiable on every open subset.